# CCLayerPanZoom won't zoom in or out

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have been having trouble with CCLayerPanZoom for weeks now and finally got close but am still having an issue.  I have a tile map that is quite large 8000 pixels x 8000 pixels and what I'd like to to is have the ability to zoom in to about 2.0f and zoom out to about 0.4f.   The below code works great in that it lets me pan around my entire tile map and NOT pan past the edges - a common problem with CCLayerPanZoom, however the code will not allow zoom in or out.   I have commented out minScale and maxScale for now since neither is working.  I have tried changing the location of minScale and maxScale and it doesn't work anywhere.  Does anyone have any ideas how to get minScale and maxScale to work so zooming will function?

```
    //PanZoomLayer

    _panZoomLayer = [[CCLayerPanZoom node] retain];
    [self addChild: _panZoomLayer];
    _panZoomLayer.delegate = self; 

    [_panZoomLayer addChild: _tileMap z :1 tag: kBackgroundTag];

    _panZoomLayer.mode = kCCLayerPanZoomModeSheet;

    _panZoomLayer.rubberEffectRatio = 0.0f;
    CCNode *backgroundZ = [_panZoomLayer getChildByTag: kBackgroundTag];
    CGRect boundingRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    boundingRect.size = [backgroundZ boundingBox].size;
    [_panZoomLayer setContentSize: boundingRect.size];

    _panZoomLayer.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f);
    _panZoomLayer.position = ccp(0.5f * winSize.width, 0.5f * winSize.height);

    _panZoomLayer.panBoundsRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, winSize.width, winSize.height);
    _panZoomLayer.minScale = 0.4f;
    _panZoomLayer.maxScale = 2.0f;

    //end PanZoomLayer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out, by adding the below line to the code above the CCPanZoomLayer finally works great.  Hopefully this code hopes others out that have struggled with this cocos2d extension

```
 [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```